# App Fog Rails Migrate Database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, command-line, migrate, appfog

How am I supposed to migrate *Rails* application database in **App Fog?**

For example, on Heroku after the first deployment you have to run:

```
$ heroku run rake db:migrate
```

Is there a similar command or the database is deployed automatically on App Fog?

P.S. I didn't found documentation for this. Does it configure the database automatically by generating the `database.yml` file like on Heroku?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is actually some documentation on [here](http://docs.appfog.com/frameworks/ruby#rake-db-seed).

Basically, you create a [Caldecott tunnel](http://docs.appfog.com/services/tunneling) with `af tunnel`, then run the migration locally.

Comment: its the same for running the rails console, what you need to do once you have your tunnel setup and running, is you have to open a new terminal window, and from your project directory run: `RAILS_ENV=proxied-appfog rails console` assuming you have setup a proxied-appfog environment as per the docs https://docs.appfog.com/languages/ruby/rails

Answer (score 0):

One option is run `af services` to see your active services. Then will display the System Services and Provisioned Services, copy your mysql Provisioned Service for your app and run `af tunnel my-app-mysql-4234` , where my-app-mysql-4234 is the name of Provisioned Service copied. Now will display 3 options, select 1 (1 option is none). Open other tab o windows terminal and run `RAILS_ENV=production rake db:migrate` where production is the name in config/database.yml.

Don't forget run `RAILS_ENV=production rake db:seed` if you need.

If it isn't clear, look this tutorial : http://eftakhairul.com/deploy-your-first-ror-app-at-appfog/

Bye!