# rake db:seed with Rails/Spree on AppFog

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rake, spree, appfog

I'm testing a Rails/Spree app on appfog, but I can't get the DB to seed. 
I've followed these instructions to the T: 
https://docs.appfog.com/languages/ruby/rails
But at the point where I run `af tunnel` and then open a new terminal window, then run `RAILS_ENV=proxied-appfog rake db:seed` I get the error

```
loading fixture /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/spree_core-1.3.2/db/default/spree/countries.yml
rake aborted!
Mysql2::Error: closed MySQL connection: SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 1
```

I'm using MySQL for the db. 
Any thoughts on why this is happening?

`rake:db migrate` runs with no errors.

`rake:db reset` fails with the same error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you run `af tunnel`, but it is incomplete. You have to run some like `af tunnel my-app-mysql-1234` and then select 1 option (none)

Check my recent answer and change the `RAILS_ENV=production rake db:migrate` per some like `RAILS_ENV=production rake db:seed`

[App Fog Rails Migrate Database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13153777/app-fog-rails-migrate-database/17103147#17103147)

Its work fine for me.

Good luck!